# detect the class of a property with name in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, introspection

I have an NSObject in objective-c at runtime and i want to know the class of a property in this object , i have the name of this property as NSString , how can I do that.

**EDIT** :

IntrospectionUtility class :

```
     @implementation IntrospectionUtility

        // this function returns an array of names of properties 


+ (NSMutableArray*) getProperties:(Class)class
    {
        NSMutableArray *properties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        unsigned int outCount, i;
        objc_property_t *objc_properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &outCount);
        for(i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = objc_properties[i];
            const char *propName = property_getName(property);
            if(propName) {
                NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:propName encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
                [properties addObject:propertyName];
            }
        }
        free(objc_properties);
        return properties;
    }

    @end
```

class test :

```
@interface JustAnExample : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *a;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *b;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *c;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *d;

@end



@implementation JustAnExample


 - (void) justAnExampleTest
 {
     NSMutableArray *attributes = [IntrospectionUtility getProperties:self.class];
    for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
       //i want to know the type of each attributte
    }

 }

@end
```

Comment: You mean without calling and checking the result?

Comment: Why or for what do you need it?

Comment: Also, do you mean your string is the name of a property on an NSString? They don't have any properties, you'll need to check the method directly.

Comment: yes the string is the name of a property which can be a nsstring or another type (nsmutableArray , nsarray ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have the name of this property as NSString

You can use the function `class_getProperty(Class cls, const char *name)` to find the property for a given class. Then use `property_getAttributes(objc_property_t property)` to get the property's attributes, including the encoded type string. Read the [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101) section of the *Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide* for more info.